# How to find a Hive Table is ACID enabled?

Tags: hive, acid

What are all the possible ways to find a given Hive Table is ACID or non-ACID?

As mentioned [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/How-to-determine-if-Hive-table-is-ACID-enabled/ta-p/247950), one way to achieve this is with below command in a Shell Script and check for the output

```
hive -e "describe extended <Database>.<tablename>;" | grep "transactional=true"
```

What are the other possible ways to achieve this? The solution can be in shell script/Apache Pig/Java which will be invoked via Oozie workflow.

Comment: What you show is a shell script, so are you asking what other ways in bash to write it? You can also use JDBC to run `describe` command in Java

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for your suggestion using jdbc (describe) in Java. Can you please advise other ways to achieve using bash

Comment: There's no other way in bash. You've already shown it

Comment: @OneCricketeer Please advise on this approach using JDBC. Running this query "show tblproperties <Table_Name>;" and checking for the value of "transactional" is true?

Comment: Sounds like it should work. Are you getting errors?

Comment: Tested this query ("show tblproperties <Table_Name>;") and its working as expected